# Unable to click on google drive element through selenium+java

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

When i tried to click on folder under google drive they are given me an null every time but i am sure my x-path is right,my confirmation is provided by fire foxfox because firefox accept my x-path.

so,can any body help me what can i do in this case.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post the code and error shots.

Comment: "they are given me" who are they?

Comment: @abhishekSharma i want to download from google drive Following are the Xpath -----------   List<WebElement> folder = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'0B601mzFemQrgaEtpNzNMS29WTWc')]/div[2]"));  but in console they are displaying null

Comment: From where u get this error

Comment: @iamsankalp89 when i trying to click on google drive its getting an exception "no such element" on console and my Xpath is definitely correct

Comment: From which page dear u click on google drive

Comment: @iamsankalp89  first i login with gmail credentials,than i click on google drive icon from gmail screen,ultimately i reach on google drive here I want to download a document through automation.

Comment: can i give code for how to click on download using actions class

Comment: @iamsankalp89 i am not using action class ,I am simply using driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'0B601mzFemQrgaEtpNzNMS29WTWc')]/div[2]")).click;

Comment: How to click on download option without right clikc

Comment: Try the below code @PiyushGarg it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in Chrome , also I would suggest use WebDriverwait instead of the implicit wait, here I used implicit as you need code for download

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\software and tools\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//goto google drive

driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/section/div[2]/div/a")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// fill emailid
driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxxx");
//click on next
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='RveJvd snByac']")).click();
// fill password driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).sendKeys("xxxxxxx");
//click on next
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='RveJvd snByac']")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


Actions act=new Actions(driver);
//move to download by right clicking and use your file xpath here    
act.contextClick(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Selenium Study')]"))).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).
sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN) 
.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.close();
```

Change emailID, password and Xpath as per your need